# Native Code and Managed Code in .NET 4

Tags: .net

The .NET 4 Global Assembly Cache is divided into 2 folders:

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_32

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL

I am intrigued  about the GAC_32 folder. Should I assume that the assemblies in this folder (like System.Data) are in native code and not managed code? Is it x86 specific?

Comment: Please take a moment to accept some of the answers to your questions. I usually do not post such comments (I rather dislike them), but 25% acceptance is pretty low.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GAC_32 and GAC_64 contain mixed-mode assemblies.  Assemblies that contain both managed code and native code.  They are generated from code produced by the C++/CLI compiler, a compiler that knows how to easily call native code from managed code without having to use pinvoke.  The assembly format is flexible enough to support both kinds of code.  A dead giveaway is seeing the `<Module>` class in the global namespace with a disassembler.

Given that they contain native code, they have a hard dependency on the machine architecture.  So you need separate copies of the assembly on a 64-bit machine.  The GAC_32 and GAC_64 folders store those separate copies, the CLR automatically picks the correct one based on the bitness of the process.

There are not that many framework assemblies that are mixed mode.  Mscorlib.dll is one, it is close to the operating system.  System.Data.dll has a strong dependency on database providers which are all available only in native code.  WPF's PresentationCore.dll has a strong dependency on Milcore, a native layer that interface to DirectX.  Etcetera.

Answer (score 2):

If you compile an assembly with AnyCPU platform it goes to MSIL folder and if you compile it with x86 platform it goes to GAC_32. [More details here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2004/09/12/228635.aspx)

You can use [CorFlags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164699%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to determine whether an assembly is x86, x64 or AnyCPU

Answer (score 0):

Decent explanation [here](http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?dotnet.12.383883.5).

> The GAC_MSIL cache contains assemblies that can be run in either
>   32-bit or 64-bit mode, and are JIT compiled to the required word size
>   as needed.
>
> The 32/64 directories contain assemblies that are specific to either
>   32-bit or 64-bit mode, either because they contain native code or
>   because they make specific assumptions about the word size.
>
> A 32-bit system will only have the GAC_32 directory.  A 64-bit system
>   will have both because 32-bit code is supported via emulation (WOW32).

I know there is some debate as to whether NGen-ed assemblies are really faster than MSIL, since a JIT-ed assembly can be optimized given the current runtime conditions (# of cores, architecture, etc.)

Comment: Regarding the last paragraph (performance): IIRC `ngen`'ed assemblies might not run faster, but *load* faster.

Comment: Yes, but they potentially run slower.  I guess that's the trade off.